# How to check if a number represents an uppercase character in NASM Assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, char, nasm, 32-bit

Suppose that you have a number stored in `EAX`. How can I check whether this number represents an uppercase character or not?

Frankly, I haven't tried anything. The closest idea I had was to create an array of upper case characters ('A','B','C,'D',...) and then check if `EAX` was equal to any of these. Is there a simpler way to do this in NASM Assembly?

I'm using 64-bit CentOS, for a 32-bit program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ASCII characters, something like this would work:

```
cmp eax,'A'
setnc bl    ; bl = (eax >= 'A') ? 1 : 0
cmp eax,'Z'+1
setc bh     ; bh = (eax <= 'Z') ? 1 : 0
and bl,bh   ; bl = (eax >= 'A' && eax <= 'Z')
; bl now contains 1 if eax contains an uppercase letter, and 0 otherwise
```

Comment: What does `setnc` and `setc` do exactly? Google isn't being very helpful with me.

Comment: You might find something if you search for "SETcc" (set on condition code), or if you look them up in Intel's manual. `SETC` sets the operand to 1 if the carry flag is set, and to 0 otherwise. `SETNC` sets the operand to 1 if the carry flag is clear, and to 0 otherwise. (a carry after a `cmp` indicates "unsigned less than", and conversely no carry indicates "unsigned greater than or equal")

Comment: Would a check for lowercase be the same, but with 'a' and 'z' instead?

Answer (score 3):

If your character is encoded in ASCII then you could just check `EAX` is in the range 65 to 90 ('A' to 'Z'). For other encodings (Unicode in primis, think about diacritics) I think the answer is not trivial at all and you should eventually use an API from the OS.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat simpler version of Michael's answer, assuming you can clobber `al`:

```
sub al, 'A'
cmp al, 'Z' + 1 - 'A'
setc al ; al now contains 1 if al contained an uppercase letter, and 0 otherwise
```

If you want to branch, then replace the `setc` with `jc` or `jnc` as appropriate.