# Checking if char is uppercase letter

Tags: assembly

I need to check if a char is an uppercase letter.
Now I know that I need to first `cmp al, "A"`, and if is above or equal, I need to `cmp al, "Z"` and then if it is less or equal, then it is an uppercase letter.
Any idea how I can do the two comparisons without having to jump labels inbetween?

Comment: Not an assembly-programmer myself, so posting as a comment rather than an answer, but why not something like: `cmp al, "A"`, `jnz END` if the comparison fails, `cmp al, "Z"`, `jnz END` if the comparison fails, then write the conversion code, then the `END` label. Doesn't strictly adhere to the "without having to jump labels" rule but it's still pretty efficient, isn't it?

Comment: See if the answer to this question is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533884/how-to-check-if-a-number-represents-an-uppercase-character-in-nasm-assembly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract `'A'` then do an unsigned comparison with `'Z'-'A'`.

```
sub al, 'A'
cmp al, 'Z'-'A'
jbe uppercase
```

Note that this of course clobbers the `al` register.

Comment: So if I don't want to clobber the `al` register, I would simply move its' content to another one and check on it, correct?

Comment: Thanks, will accept the answer once it allows me to.

Comment: If you don't want to clobber the register, do two comparisons - with 'A' and with 'Z'.

Comment: Seva, but that would have to take two jumps inbetween, no?

Comment: Hint: you can use `LEA` to do the copy and the subtract in one step, if you have a free 32 bit register.

Comment: @Jester, I have a question. Suppose the char is '$', of dec code 36. Now, `sub al, 'A'` gives -29, and it is below or equal `'Z' - 'A'` which is 25. Why doesn't it consider it an uppercase letter, then?

Comment: Because I used an unsigned conditional jump which interprets the `-29` as `227`.