# Assembly find if written symbol is number

Tags: assembly, compare, tasm

I'm lost in assembly magical world. Is there a possibility to check in assembly (I'm using TASM) if typed in symbol is whether number or other symbol? Example: I type in 'A' and program prints out it's not a number and end a program. And if I type in number, it continues the program.

And another question on the same page (to not create new post): How do I compare if written string is something program expects? For example if you type in '/?' the program prints out certain message?

Any answers greatly appreciated.

Here's my written program, where I need to implement these functions:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data 
    abc db 10
    eilmax db 10, ?, 10 dup(0)

.code
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov dx, offset eilmax
    int 21h
    mov ax, 0
    mov bx, offset eilmax[2]
    jmp change  

change:             ;written number converts from ascii to dec
    mov ch, 0
    mov cl, byte ptr [bx]
    cmp cl, 13
    je fibo
    sub cl, 48
    mul abc
    add ax, cx 
    inc bx
    jmp change    

fibo:              
    mov bx, 0
    mov cx, 1

findfibo:           ;finds n-th number of fibonacci sequence
    add bx, cx
    mov dx, bx
    mov bx, cx
    mov cx, dx
    sub ax, 1
    cmp ax, 1 
    je  find
    jmp findfibo 

find:              ;finds if number is less or greater than 10
    cmp bx, 10
    jge convert
    jmp writesmall

convert:            ;if number is > 10, program devides number to two numbers
    mov dx, 0
    mov ax, 0
    mov ax, bx
    mov bx, 10
    div bx
    jmp writebig

writebig:          ;prints out greater than 10 found number
    mov bx, 0
    mov bx, dx
    mov dx, 0
    add ax, 48
    mov dx, ax
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    add bx, 48
    mov dx, bx
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    jmp chg

writesmall:          ;print out less than 10 found number
    add bx, 48 
    mov dx, bx  
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    jmp chg

chg:                ;end program
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

end start
```

Comment: Of course it is possible, you just need to compare the input with your expectations. For the digits, you can use the fact that `0..9` are consecutive in ascii.

Comment: I am thinking of doing 10 cycles (for every number from 0 to 9) for comparing the symbol, but I know it's not the solution. How could I do it in one cycle?

Comment: As I said, they are consecutive, so you only need to check `c >= '0' && c <= '9'`. You can transform that into `(c - '0') <= '9'-'0'` with unsigned comparison.

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254993/checking-if-char-is-uppercase-letter/22255150).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASCII numbers will be in range (0x30 ;0x30 +9)//48 in decimal (first question)

Interrupts that might be helpful:

`INT 16h / AH = 00h` - get keystroke from keyboard (no echo).
    AL = ASCII character.

`INT 16h / AH = 01h` - check for keystroke in the keyboard buffer.
    AL = ASCII character.

Instruction set for strings (second question):

`CMPSB` -Compare bytes: ES:[DI] from DS:[SI].

`LODSB` -Load byte at DS:[SI] into AL. Update SI.

`MOVSB` -Copy byte at DS:[SI] to ES:[DI]. Update SI and DI.

`SCASB` -Compare bytes: `AL` from `ES:[DI]`.

`STOSB` -Store byte in `AL` into `ES:[DI]`. Update `DI.`

`REP`   -repeat above function  cx times

For examples and documentation refer to:
[emu8086 documentation](https://github.com/AhmadAbdelNaser/emu8086/tree/master/documentation)